# Как найти минимальное число квадратов кроме самого себя, которыми можно покрыть квадрат?

Tags: алгоритм

Как найти это минимальное число на интуитивном уровне - понятно (см. рисунок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пусть задана сторона квадрата `n`, тогда
это число равняется:

`min = 4 + (n^2 - (3*floor(n/2)^2 + ceil(n/2)^2)` (1)

то есть для четных `n`, `min = 4`, а для нечётных `min = 4 + кол-во единичных квадратов`

Но непонятно, как формально доказать формулу (1)?

То есть что вот это

`(n^2 - (3*floor(n/2)^2 + ceil(n/2)^2)`

есть ни что иное, как минимально необходимое количество единичных квадратов.

**update**

как оказалось, формула 1 не оптимальна в общем случае (см пример @Harry)

Тогда вопрос:

Как найти минимальное число квадратов кроме самого себя, которыми можно покрыть этот квадрат ?

Comment: Вам надо доказать формулу для вашего решения, или доказать, что такое ваше решение - оптимальное? Вообще-то квадрат покрывается одном квадратом, кстати :)

Comment: @Harry что это решение оптимально ) ну и понятно что покрытие самим собой не учитываем, ввиду тривиальности

Comment: А оно и не оптимально в общем случае...

Comment: @Harry это почему ?

Comment: Для 7X7 [ответ](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/mathmagic/1298/g7.gif): 9. Задача не очень тривиальная, есть сведение к простым множителям, но дальше хорошей формулы нет: [1](https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/mathmagic/1298.html), [2](http://oeis.org/A018835)

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае ваше решение не оптимально. Для доказательства, к счастью, достаточно контрпримера - вот он:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева - ваше решение, справа - немного получше (не буду утверждать, что оптимальное).

Тьфу, ну я даю... Тут же вообще можно было поделить квадрат 9x9 на 9 квадратов 3x3! Ладно, оставлю уж свой позорняк... :)

Comment: мдауж, тривиальность этой задачи все больше и больше улетучивается

Comment: Недаром я с детства не очень любил геометрию :)

Comment: @Kromster Как раз на **поставленный** вопрос - как *доказать* приведенную формулу (1) - он отвечает: никак, формула не верна :)

Comment: @Kromster правильно казалось, тут вобщн весь вопрос в том, чтобы найти оптимальную формулу

Comment: @Harry обновил пост. Тогда какой алгоритм нахождения минимальноно числа квадратов ?

Comment: А вот теперь - хоть удаляй ответ, потому что есть у меня подозрение, что красивого решения не существует... Ведь даже разбиение квадрата на сумму квадратов не гарантирует, что эти квадраты улягутся вместе в больший квадрат...

Comment: Впрочем, взгляните сюда - на [квадрирование квадрата](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: Ну вот .. ваш ответ опять не отвечает на поставленный вопрос КАК. И опять выглядит как комментарий ..

Comment: @Kromster Ну конечно, если кардинально изменить вопрос по ходу дела - то все ответы на предыдущий будут не более чем комментарии :) Вы не пробовали задачку "найти тройку чисел, сумма квадратов первых двух равна квадрату третьего" сменить на "а для n-ой степени?", а в ответ на "таких нет" опять изменить вопрос на "доказать, что"?... :) Тем более что задача - судя по тому, что ей уже скоро 100 лет, а формулы так и нет - как минимум *простого* решения не имеет...

Comment: Вот поэтому я на такие "мутные" вопросы и не отвечаю, пока не получу от ТС нормальной формулировки. А после ее получения и ответа - отправляю задавать новый вопрос, а не дополнять старый. В данном же случае, данный ответ, что на изначальный вопрос, что на текущий - скорее комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @Harry здравствуйте, а где можно про это почитать?) речь про натуральные числа?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ О чем? о тройках чисел?